# Solution to replace TLC2272CP IC

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, solar-charge-controller

I am trying to build the following circuit that works as a solar power charging controller.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find IC1 named as TLC2272CP that works as dual low-noise rail-to- rail operational amplifier exhibits rail-to-rail output IC.

[image]

Can anyone help me rebuild this circuit design in order to replace it or is their a cheap replacement for it?

Comment: The TLC2272 is an improved version of the TLC272. You may find the latter easier. For the given application, almost any rail-to-rail/single-supply dual-OP-amp will work.

Comment: Great thanks Mr Janka kindly can you suggest to me a popular cheap one

Comment: The TLC272, it's €1,50 per piece. If you can't get your hands on it (unlikely), search for *rail-to-rail* or *single-supply*.

Comment: It's not available. I need it to be as cheap as you can

Comment: TZ1 isn't a fuse but an overvoltage protector. You want this because lightning may hit near your solar panels, creating transients on its terminals.

Comment: Can you suugest a replacement part for TZ1 also!

Comment: I just found a 10 year old thread https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/88590 in which someone had exactly the same parts problems you have. [^_^;]

Comment: Hhhhh yobe i am not the only dumme on this world. Unfortunately i can't read any since i guess its in German language ^_^

Comment: They recommended a transzorbs (suppressor diodes) of the *P6KE6.8CA* series from *Littlefuse*. You have to select the voltage higher than that of your solar panel.

Comment: Aha now i understand great thanks. Any ideas for cheap ic

Comment: There are sure dozens but I don't know what's available at your place. You aren't limited to dual-OP-Amps either.

Comment: Can you name the most popular ones so i can search for them in my place tomorrow

Comment: Sorry, no clue.

Comment: Clue for what !?

Comment: Can LM 358 be tried as it is not very specific.

Comment: I used Lm 358 .Ocilating frequency is 370 hz and it is working

Answer (score 4):

IC1a is called a "float voltage **comparator**" in the schematic. IC1b is configured as an oscillator. The device operates from a +5V single supply.

Both sections of the device are operating as comparators, not op amps. Both functions can be achieved (better) with push-pull comparators rather than op amps because, well, comparators are designed to be comparators and low noise op amps are designed to be low noise op amps. Low noise is not required at all for these circuits to function as designed.

You can look for devices on manufacturer websites (TI, LT, Microchip, etc.) or distributor websites (Mouser, Digikey, etc.). Distributor sites are sufficient for most things, but you should look at specific manufacturer sites if you have a very specific application or requirement. [Here is a Mouser page filtered to show >5V dual push-pull comparators in DIP-8 and SO-8 packages sorted by price](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Amplifier-ICs/Analog-Comparators/_/N-cib1wZ1yzvvqx?P=1z0y3wbZ1z0z7v3Z1z0z7zfZ1z0z7v5Z1z0jllrZ1yuyxfiZ1yzxao2Z1yzmm03Z1yzmm18Z1yzmm1bZ1yzmlz3Z1yzmlyoZ1yzmm1dZ1yzmlt2Z1yzmm0fZ1yzmm0wZ1yzmm09Z1yzmm07Z1yzmlzaZ1yzmm0vZ1yzmlvlZ1yzmlyq&Ns=Pricing%7C0) to get you started.

My default comparator in this application would be an MCP6542, which happens to be the cheapest one on that Mouser page. (Note that it has a rail-to-rail input, but **does not** have a rail-to-rail output. That doesn't matter at all in the circuit.)

Comment: If i use a pair of LM741 it will work fine !?

Comment: @Ahmad - Define 'fine.' The application is fairly simple and non-critical, so using op amps is feasible. Whether or not their performance is adequate depends on your requirements.

Comment: I mean that LM741 is available and its cheep while on the other hand it isn't rail to rail input or output so what you suugest !?

Comment: I asked for MCP6542 and unfortunately i didn't find it

Comment: @Ahmad - The circuit design does not require rail-to-rail input or output. Try the LM741 if it's all you've got. Oscillator frequency might change a bit (doesn't matter) and float voltage set-point accuracy will decrease (probably not much).

Comment: I will try that. For diode 20L15T can i use normal 20 amp diode !

Comment: @Ahmad 20L15T is a Schottky diode. I think a standard silicon diode will work, but will have much higher losses.

Comment: Hello Mr.vofa I saw that 20L15T is a 20A 15V shottcky rectifier. What if u use a normal silicon diode or normal shottcky diode that diliver 20 amp without rectifying  !? And for diode two that named as 1N5818 can i use a zener diode insted of it with the same voltage !?

Comment: And also can i add a 12v dc power load line to get from it 12v 10-20 amp load when my solar power is charging !? Can you make this edit in the circuit Sir

Comment: @ahmad Post these as new questions.